# I can't get this command to work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is the command I used:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ 
    execute @e[type=Villager,c=1] ~ ~ ~ 
        /summon Item ~ ~ ~-1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",count:5}}
```

I used it to summon 5 diamonds near the only villager but it doesn't seems to work, if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please give details to the effect you get. Error message or wrong result? Do simpler commands work? What Minecraft version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In the command, `Count` has to be capitalized.  I also added `b` following the number to specify data type.

Here is a working command:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=villager,c=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Item ~ ~ ~-1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:5b}}
```

This will summon 5 diamonds one block away from the nearest villager to each player.